# Assigning Observable to another

Tags: swift, rx-swift

I have this object `TryOut`, when initialize, it executes a private method every `2 seconds`. Within that method **func execute()** there is ,`internalStream`, a local variable of type `Observable<Int>` that captures data that I wish to emit to the outside world.

> The issue is that even though `internalStream` is assigning to a member property  `public var outsideStream: Observable<Int>?`, There aren't any events coming from subscribing to `outsideStream`. Why though ? is there any reason behind that ?

**Working Case**

The only way it work, is by having a closure as member property `public var broadcast:((Observable<Int>) -> ())? = nil`, and raise it within the `execute` method by doing this `broadcast?(internalStream)`

A sample code could be found in this [gist](https://gist.github.com/LamourBt/ef65a5345e4d2c3d117e8616f9945e47). Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this kind of situation, when you want to produce events by yourself, you should better use any of `*Subject` provided by `RxSwift`.

For example:

Change `outputStream` declaration to:

```
public var outsideStream = PublishSubject<Int>()
```

Produce events in right way:

```
@objc private func execute() {
    currentIndex += 1

    if currentIndex < data.count {
        outsideStream.onNext(data[currentIndex])
    }

    guard currentIndex + 1 > data.count && timer.isValid else { return }
    outsideStream.onCompleted()
    timer.invalidate()
}
```

And the usage:

```
let participant = TryOut()
participant.outsideStream
    .subscribe(
        onNext: { print("income index:", $0) },
        onCompleted: { print("stream completed") }
    )
    .disposed(by: bag)
```

gives you the output:

```
income index: 1
income index: 2
income index: 3
income index: 4
income index: 5
stream completed
```

P.S. Also, there is another way to do that by using (or reproduce) [`retry`](https://github.com/RxSwiftCommunity/RxSwiftExt#retry) method by `RxSwiftExt` library.